# Отличие работы кода в Mozilla и Chrome

Tags: button, firefox, click

Есть код

```
    <body onclick='alert(event.target.tagName)'><button><i>Button</i></button></body>
```

При клике на кнопке на **слово Button** в Chrome выдаёт **I**, а Mozilla  - **BUTTON**. Почему так и как сделать так, чтобы и в Mozilla выдаrвался самый глубокий элемент

Comment: А почему вы уверены, что Хром ведет себя правильно в данном случае?

Comment: Потому, что если вместо тега BUTTON использовать любой другой, например, DIV, то в обоих браузерах всё работает одинаково и выдаёт самый глубокий тег, т.е. I

Comment: Так я вам скажу, что IE ведет себя как Лиса, а не Хром.

Comment: тогда почему <body onclick='alert(event.target.tagName)'><div><i>Button</i></div></body> выдаёт I? Смысл ведь тот же, только тег другой

Comment: @Юлия кроме как "особенности реализации в конкретном браузере", видимо, это не назвать.

Comment: Вы в этом уверены? Может это особенность тега Button? Почему тогда div работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17253410

Answer (score 9):

Похоже, Firefox следует [рекомендациям W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element):

> Content model:
>   Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

То есть `<button>` может содержать [Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) - текст и/или один или несколько элементов из списка:

> a, abbr, area (если он потомок элемента map), audio, b, bdi, bdo, br, button, canvas, cite, code, data, datalist, del, dfn, em, embed, i, iframe, img, input, ins, kbd, keygen, label, map, mark, math, meter, noscript, object, output, progress, q, ruby, s, samp, script, select, small, span, strong, sub, sup, svg, template, textarea, time, u, var, video, wbr, text

Но контент внутри `<button>` не может быть интерактивным. В рекомендациях W3C описано что есть [интерактивность](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0). Интерактивными элементами могут быть:

> a, audio (если присутствует атрибут controls), button, embed, iframe, img (если присутствует атрибут usemap), input (если атрибут type не равен hidden), keygen, label, object (если присутствует атрибут usemap), select, textarea, video (если присутствует атрибут controls)

Эти элементы имеют activation behavior, которое определяет механизм активации элемента.

Когда пользователь щёлкает по элементу, происходит поиск ближайшего интерактивного элемента, начиная с элемента, по которому щёлкнули, вверх по дереву ищется первый элемент с activation behavior. Если такой элемент найден, ему отправляется событие `click`.

В вашем примере `<i>` не является интерактивным. А ближайшим интерактивным является `<button>`, поэтому события `click` срабатывают на `<button>`.

В качестве решения можно использовать `<div>` или `<span>`, стилизованный под `<button>`

Comment: Большое спасибо за конкретнейший ответ