# Firefox + a, вложенные в button = не работает клик

Tags: javascript, firefox

Вот эта штука работает в хроме, но не работает в тормозилле:

```html
<button>
<a href='#' onclick='alert("Hello, chrome user")'>Click me</a>
</button>
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Посмотрите, был уже подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545739/196740