# Почему данный пример не будет работать в Firefox?

Tags: css, css3, reactjs, firefox

Задача: нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку btn1 вызывался клик по кнопке btn2 (кнопка btn2 не должна быть видна).

Вот пример реализации

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (btn) => () => {
    console.log(`click ${btn}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homePage">
        <button className="btn btn1" onClick={this.handleClick('btn1')}>
          Btn1
          <span className="btn btn2" onClick={this.handleClick('btn2')}>Btn2</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

```css
.homePage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: navajowhite;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.btn1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Данный пример будет работать в Chrome, но в Firefox работать не будет, см. [видео](https://monosnap.com/file/UlrMOyeW2aPbPwX5TKBEiskT).

Помогите разобраться почему и как можно починить чтобы работало в Firefox, не меняя разметки??

Если вы хотите увидеть .btn2 на примере поменяйте в CSS классу .btn2 свойство opacity на 1. При щелчке выводится сообщение в консоль, где отображается имя кнопки по которой щёлкнули.

Comment: Класть что-то кроме текста внутри тега button - плохая идея. Разные браузеры отработают это по разному и строго говоря именно поведение хрома считается багом (пруфов не будет, лень искать =)). Идеологически верный путь - именно поменять разметку например сделав вместо батонов дивы в виде батонов

Comment: Ну и да, здесь пофигу реакт не реакт. Ваш пример можно упростить до такого https://jsfiddle.net/ptm1ycf1/  Обратите внимание что IE ведет себя аналогично ff

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545739